# Where to put stub classes in Maven projects

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, stubs

I have a Maven project with the following directory layout:

```
    .
└── src    
     ├── main
     │    └── ...
     └── test
           └── java
                 └── com.foo
                      ├── stubs
                      │   └── JsonSnippets.java
                      ├── bar
                      │   └── BarTest.java
                      └── ... further tests
```

The `JsonSnippets` class looks like this:

```java
package com.foo.stubs;

public class JsonSnippets {

    public final static String SNIPPET_A = "{...}";

}
```

Within the `BarTest` class, I want to use the `JsonSnippets` class, therefore I have

```
package com.foo.bar;

import com.foo.stubs.JsonSnippets;

// ...

@Test
public void testWithJsonSnippets() {
    String json = JsonSnippets.SNIPPET_A;
    // ...
}
```

When I now run `mvn test`, I get the following error message:

```
cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class JsonSnippets
[ERROR] location: package com.foo.bar
```

**Remark** everything works as expected, when I put the `JsonSnippets` class into the `src/main/...` package / directory.

Comment: Is the `JSonSnippets` class public?

Comment: yes - it is declared public - I will add this to my question, thx for asking!

Comment: Could you also append the JsonSnippets class.

Comment: Can you check whether the JsonSnippets class is within your class path (target/test-classes)?

Comment: @uniknow - yes - the `JsonSnippets` is now compiled to `test-classes/.../stups/JsonSnippets.class` but still I cannot import / use it in my Test class (at least within IntelliJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was a broken Maven configuration in the project's directory. After I removed all non-project related cache files and created the project "from scratch" (with exactly the same sources), everything worked as described in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have imported the JsonSnippet class properly or not.

Check if JsonSnippet  class has public constructor defined.

Comment: I guess `import com.foo.stubs.JsonSnippets;` is the proper import of the class and I don't need a public constructor for a class that only contains static members - am I right?